# Which overloaded method will be called?

Tags: int, byte, overloading, overriding

I have two overloaded methods. One is having var arg of type int and other having var arg of type byte. If I call the method and pass some value (say int) will my program compile ? and if yes which method will be called?

Comment: What language? What invocation? Please show an example.

Answer (score 0):

Java Code:

```
package Test;    

public class Test {

        private static void m1(int... args) {
            System.out.println("int one got executed");
        }

        private static void m1(byte... args) {
            System.out.println("byte one got executed");
        }

        public static void main(String... args) {
            m1(400);
        }

    }
```

And the result:

> int one got executed
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Thanks Berkin ! I executed similar code and int method got executed.

Answer (score 0):

public class Test
{

```
public void m1(byte b)
{
    System.out.println("byte "+b);
}

public void m1(int a)
{
    System.out.println("int "+a);
}




public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Test t =new  Test();
    t.m1(5);
    t.m1(100);
}
```

}

Output: 
int 5
int 100